# how to upload images from server in jdeveloper forms?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hi users i want to upload images and also want to edit images in another page like paint etc .Also i want to save that edited copy?is these are possible in jdeveloper?please help me?i have no idea about this>please help

Comment: Please put some attempt and show us what you have done so far. You have to make use of af:inputFile component to upload the image.

Answer (score 0):

Info on image uploading is here: http://tompeez.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/jdev11-1-2-1-0-handling-imagesfiles-in-adf-part-3/ There is no built-in functionality in ADF to allow you to edit images. You'll need to integrate a third party solution for this.